Subset error after importing with readr ("arguments imply differing number of rows") in Quarto R chunk
I can't subset rows after importing a csv with readr::read_csv from a .qmd.
Data example
Create a file called BSI_test8.csv with these two rows:
id,data_collection_date,data_collection,reporting_organisation_code,specimen_date,specimen_time,week_no,icu_admission_date,icu_admission_time
478574,01/01/1900,ICU BSI,ABC1,01/01/1900,12:00,1,31/12/1899,23:00

Code

Create a .qmd file
Insert a new R code chunk
Paste the following code in that chunk:

linelist_pbc_raw <-
    readr::read_csv("./BSI_test8.csv", show_col_types = FALSE)

linelist_pbc_raw[linelist_pbc_raw$specimen_date != linelist_pbc_raw$data_collection_date, ]


Run the chunk.

Error
I get this error:
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

I don't understand what this error means, as both columns have the same number of rows (in this example, 1).
What works
I have found these workarounds:

Running the exact same subsetting code directly from the console

From an R chunk, removing some other date columns from the dataset before subsetting (in this MRE, just the time columns):


linelist_pbc_raw |>
    subset(specimen_date != data_collection_date,
           select = -c(specimen_time, icu_admission_time))


From an R chunk, using data.table::fread to import the data before subsetting

linelist_pbc_raw_datatable <-
    data.table::fread("./BSI_test8.csv")

linelist_pbc_raw_datatable[linelist_pbc_raw_datatable$specimen_date != linelist_pbc_raw_datatable$data_collection_date, ]

I imagine this might be a bug in the way that readr imports data without a final empty line and the way RStudio runs the R chunks within a qmd file. Any idea why this might happen?
R version 4.4.1
RStudio version 2024.9.0.375
OS: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Does this also happen if you instead use read.delim(sep = "|")? If not it might be best to open an issue in the readr GitHub repo.

Can you reproduce the error with a small dataset? Or at least share ./extract.txt?

@MikkoMarttila it doesn't happen with read.delim, this seems to confirm that the problem lies with readr - will raise an issue on GH.

@s_baldur I can't share the file. I'll try and create a file with fake data to reproduce the issue

What does names(linelist_pbc_raw) return? If you run ls() do you have any variable names that match column names? This would be much easier if you could provide a simple reproducible example.

@MrFlick provided MRE. ls() only returns "linelist_pbc_raw" in this fresh session.

I cannot replicate with the sample provided. The code runs without error for me. Tested with R 4.3.3 and readr_2.1.5 and dplyr_1.1.4

@MrFlick Apologies - I've now realised that the issue only happens when code is run from a .qmd file. I've now edited the question to reflect this so the issue should now be reproducible.

I've raised this as an issue on RStudio's GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/15459
